# why are validation directives/properties not set on field?

Tags: angularjs, validation

See this **plunkr** :

https://plnkr.co/edit/vQvgVSAfMLh3kPRKDFP2?p=preview

I have written minlength, maxlength & validation attributes on the mname field but their $valid,$dirty & $pristine properties are somehow not being set. & thus I am unable to show error messages.

I can verify that form is invalid by passing the form to the controller & adding an alert there.

**HTML Code**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="emi" >
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Empty AngularJS</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.18/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.18/angular-messages.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <section data-ng-controller="emiController">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>

    <form name="MyEmiForm" novalidate data-ng-submit="create(MyEmiForm)" >  

    <div>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" id="mname"  
            placeholder="Name" required ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="8"/>


            <br>
            Form Valid : {{MyEmiForm.$valid }} <br>
            {{MyEmiForm.mname.$error }}<br>
        mname   Valid : {{MyEmiForm.mname.$valid }}<br>
        mname   Dirty : {{MyEmiForm.mname.$dirty }}<br>
        mname   Pristine : {{MyEmiForm.mname.$pristine}}<br>
        mname   Touched : {{MyEmiForm.mname.$touched }}<br>
            DOB Valid : {{MyEmiForm.dob.$valid }}<br>

             <span class="help-block" 
              ng-show="MyEmiForm.mname.$invalid && !MyEmiForm.mname.$pristine">
         You name is required.
       </span>


<div ng-messages="MyEmiForm.mname.$error" >
  <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="dob">DOB</label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" data-ng-model="dob" id="dob" placeholder="DOB" required/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="submit" >
    </div>
    <div data-ng-show="error">
        <strong data-ng-bind="error"></strong>
    </div>
    </form>
</section>  
</body>
</html>
```

**Script File**

```
angular.module('emi', ['ngMessages']) //[] re-initialize, w/o []. use exiting
.controller('emiController', 
['$scope' ,
    function($scope)
    {   

    $scope.title = "New Emi Calculation";

        $scope.create = function(form) {
        if(!form.$valid)
        {
            alert("Not ok");
            return;
        }
        alert("All ok");
        }   


    }   
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add name attribute to input

```
<input type="text"  name='mname' data-ng-model="name" id="mname"  
            placeholder="Name" required ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="8"/>
```